# Test-Path but also list whether target machine is offline

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that goes down a list of computers and tells me if the folder I ask for is available on that PC. The problem with this is that it lists offline PCs as false.

I would like it to list offline PCs as offline or just add extra info if it is.
I don't mind it saying it's false as long as I know if the PC is online or not.

What I have so far:

```
Get-Content c:\computers.txt | `
   Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='FolderExist';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c$\program files (x86)\thefolder"}}
```

Comment: Add a check before this step to see if the computer is on. For example, check if the computer has path `C:\`. If not, call it "offline". Otherwise, continue to the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

This will still have FolderExist False for offline computers but you'll see which is online.

```
Get-Content .\computers.txt |
   Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},
     @{Name='Online';Expression={(Test-Connection $_ -count 1 -EA 0).StatusCode -eq 0}},
     @{Name='FolderExist';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c`$\program files (x86)\common files"}}
```

Sample output:

```
ComputerName Online FolderExist
------------ ------ -----------
Computer01     True        True
Computer02    False       False
Computer03     True       False
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
    Get-Content .\computers.txt |
       Select-Object @{n='ComputerName';e={$_}},
                     @{n='FolderExist';e={ If(Test-Connection $_ -Quiet -Count1){Test-Path "\\$_\c`$\program files (x86)\common files"}else{"Offline"}}}
```